# Date and Time Format in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis

I have a date and time format:

```
Interval Start Time
1/13/16 1:30:00 
1/15/16 10:30:00
```

Desired Result

```
Interval Start Time
13/01/2016 13:30:00 (24 Hr)
15/01/2016 10:30:00
```

The Interval Time is between 08:00 to 17:30.

I would like it to be: 13/01/2016 13:30 and 15/01/2016 10:30:00 and I devised this In SSIS derived Column:

```
 (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],3,2) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],1,1) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],6,2) + " " +  
 SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],9,1) == 1 ? "13" : 
 SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],9,1) == 2 ? "14" :
 SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],9,1) == 3 ? "15" : 
 SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],9,1) == 4 ? "16" :  
 SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],9,1) == 5 ? "17" : 
 "[Interval Start Time]" )
 + ":" + SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],11,2))
```

The error I get in SSIS is:

> ...The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element...

and I am not sure if the formula is correct in what I want it to do either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the last parentheses ')' is to remove...

Comment: `SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],11,2))` as @alex says, remove the last parenthesis so it's `SUBSTRING([Interval Start Time],11,2)` but I think you will still receive errors with the equality `== 1, == 2, == 3 ...` checks as you are comparing a string type and a numeric type. What data type is this `[Interval Start Time]` stored as and in what DBMS?

Comment: What is the data type for `[Interval Start Time]`? Is it a `STRING` or a `DATETIME` type?

Comment: The data type for [Interval Start Time] is STRING. Thanks

Comment: What locale is your OS set to?

Comment: In your original data . how can we tell whether the first value there was AM or PM?

Comment: Locale is set to English (United Kingdom). You can't tell its AM or PM. The Service runs from 08:00 to 17:00 so there shouldn't any 12 hour time formats.

Answer (score 2):

Before present a possible solution here, I want you be aware about some errors in your approach. Using expressions for this requeriment is very complex and hard to maintain, besides what happen when your `Interval Start Time` column have dates from October (10) to December (12) months, your string lenght will change and your hardcoded solution via `SUBSTRING` calls will return absurd data and produce error while package is running.

**SOLUTION:** Use Script component.

1. After creating your source, add a Script Component and link the source to it.
2. Configure the Script component to include `Interval Start Time` column by selecting it in `Input Columns` tab.
3. Add an output column, name it as you want and choose database timestamp (DT_DBTIMESTAMP).
   [image]
4. Go to Script tab, and press the Edit Script... button.
5. Use the below code to overwrite the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` function.

   ```
   public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   {
       /*
       * Add your code here
       */
       var str_timestamp = Row.IntervalStartTime.ToString();
       string[] arr = str_timestamp.Trim().Split(' ');
       string[] date = arr[0].Split('/');
       string[] time = arr[1].Split(':');

       string formatedDate = "20" + date[2] + "-" + date[0].PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" + date[1].PadLeft(2, '0');
       int hour = Convert.ToInt32(time[0]);
       int hour_24 = hour < 8 ? hour + 12 : hour;
       formatedDate += " " + hour_24 + ":" + time[1] + ":" + time[2];

       Row.MyColumn = Convert.ToDateTime(formatedDate);

   }
   ```
6. In `Row.MyColumn`, replace `MyColumn` by the given name of your output column.
7. Save changes in Visual Studio and close the editor.

Now you can add a destination after the Script component and you will see the formatted IntervalStartTime as you need.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.